# Como remover caracteres de string

Tags: python

Ola eu tenho o seguinte codigo:

```py
lista_valores = ["20.000","2.000"]
for valores in lista_valores:
    valor = valores.strip(".000")
    print(valor)
```

E seu resultado é:

```
2
2
```

Porem meu objetivo é obter os valores sem as casa decimais
assim:

```
20
2
```

Eu tentei usar o `strip` porem não deu certo, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Dê uma olhada na [documentação do método `str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: Seria uma opção porem a variável seria retornada como uma lista, o que não seria útil para mim

Comment: Na verdade essa é sua melhor opção, separar em variáveis diferentes é um outro problema, mas pode ser resolvido facilmente usando `milhares, unidades = "20.000".split(".")` ou você pode ignorar a segunda parte com `milhares, _, _ = "20.000".partition("/")`

Comment: @PauloMarques Com `int` não funciona: https://ideone.com/g3WI3Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strip` recebe a lista de caracteres a serem removidos do início e fim da string, ou seja, você está removendo **todos** os zeros e pontos do final, por isso que "20.000" se torna "2".

Se as strings representam números, então converta-as para valores numéricos usando `float`:

```
lista_valores = ["20.000","2.000"]
for valores in lista_valores:
    valor = float(valores)
    print(valor)
```

Só que isso imprime "20.0" e "2.0". Se quer arredondar e eliminar as casas decimais, use `round`:

```
lista_valores = ["20.000","2.000"]
for valores in lista_valores:
    valor = round(float(valores))
    print(valor)
```

Aí ele imprime "20" e "2".

Outra opção, como indicado nos comentários, é formatando o valor:

```
lista_valores = ["20.000","2.000"]
for valores in lista_valores:
    print(f'{float(valores):.0f}')
```

No caso, `.0f` indica que o número deve ser formatado com zero casas decimais. Veja a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) para mais detalhes.

---

Manipular a string, como sugeriram as outras respostas (que foram apagadas), não é o ideal, pois se mudar a quantidade de casas decimais aí elas  não funcionariam mais. Já convertendo para números usando as funções corretas, você evita esses problemas.

Comment: Entendi tudo muito obrigado por esclarecer